# /proc/meminfo: meaning of some values

Tags: linux, memory-usage

Is it true when talking about values in `/proc/meminfo` file?

> [Memory used by applications] = MemTotal - (MemFree + Buffers + Cached + SwapCached)

Comment: What is `/etc/meminfo`?  Are you sure you aren't talking about `/proc/meminfo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you are saying is essentially correct. That is one rough way to get the memory used by applications.

The formula holds true, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

A great article breaking down meminfo can be found on RedHat's site [here](http://www.redhat.com/advice/tips/meminfo.html)

For the record:

**MemTotal**: Total usable ram (i.e. physical ram minus a few reserved bits and the kernel binary code).

Also, its not that exact of a science when figuring out available and used memory. Linux caches all the memory it can and uses it as needed.

Free -m will help display the current memory usage in MB

```
free -m
```

It would also be beneficial to visit [LinuxAteMyRAM](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

Comment: That doesn't contradict the asker's statement, though... nor really confirm it. Just covers all the background related.